# How to create an alert when cells automatically change value?

Tags: vba, excel

In one of my worksheets, I have either the value Yes or No in cells F2:F18

What I basically want to do is create a popup which will alert me when they change.

Initially I had the following, which appeared to work fine, however because the Yes/No values are generated by a formula, it doesn't work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & myRange.Address & " is now equal to Yes"
    End If
End Sub

Sub BandingAlert()
    Dim myRange As Object
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F18")
    Call Worksheet_Change(myRange)
End Sub
```

After some research, I found I needed to use Worksheet_Calculate instead.  I am now using the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim myRange As Object
    Set myRange= ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F18")
    If myRange.Value = "Yes" Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & myRange.Address & " is now equal to Yes"
    End If
End Sub
```

When the Yes/No values change, I now get an error of

> Run-time error '13'; 
>   Type Mismatch

If I debug my code, the row highlighted is:

```
If myRange.Value = "Yes" Then
```

Can anyone help me out with where I am going wrong please?

EDIT:  Each cell will need its own pop up as I plan to put cell specific information in each pop up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra Range variable to iterate over your Range collection.

Your `myRange` variable is a collection of cells in between `F2:F18`. In order to acces each cell in that range you need to iterate through it.

I have added an extra Range variable called `cell` that acts as the iterator. In the `for each` loop the `cell` variable is the active cell.

The [StrComp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s233cfc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function compares the current active cell's value against `"Yes"`. The `vbTextCompare` ignores the case and compares the text literally.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F18")
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In myRange
        Evaluate (cell)
        If StrComp(cell, "Yes", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address & " is now equal to Yes"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You will be shown a `MsgBox` for each `Yes` in Range `F2:F18` everytime the sheet recalculates. It may become a bit annoying in a while but it's what you were looking for, aint it?

Comment: This doesn't throw up any errors, however when the values of the cell change, there isn't a popup.  The values in the cells F2:F18 are generated by an IF statement that relies on the values of other cells in a different worksheet.  I don't believe that would make a difference to how this works though?

Comment: are you sure you've stick this code in the SheetN object module and not a standard module? Also, are you sure your `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` ?

Comment: Yep, the code is in Sheet20 which is the correct sheet.  What do you mean about the Application.Calculation part?

Comment: @Xeo are you the only person who writes code to the file? If you haven't changed the Application.Calculation anywhere in the code you should be fine. But if you did then the sheet may need to be recalculated manually i think its F9 to recalculate.

Comment: @mehow Yes, nobody else will be changing the code, others will have access to the excel file though (just not the vba)  F9 works, however is there no way I can get this to run as soon as the cells change?  It needs to be automated

Comment: @Xeo create a new workbook. stick `1` in `D2` and `0` in `E2` and put this formula in `F2` `=IF(D2=E2, "yes", "no")`. then stick the code ive given you in the answer in the sheet1 object model code and go back to sheet and change `0` to `1`. does this not work for you?

Comment: @mehow that seems to work, however if I set E2 to equal A1 on Sheet2 for example, then change the value of Sheet2!A1 it doesn't work.  Something is stopping to pop up working because the values come from a separate sheet I think.

Comment: Argh, I thought Worksheet_Calculate event would work due to the values being change on that worksheet either directly or indirectly

Comment: thanks @pnuts, and [yea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002609/auto-install-my-application-if-user-reinstall-windows/19003354#19003354)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim myRange As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim CellAddr As String

    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F18")

    For Each aCell In myRange
        If aCell.Value = "Yes" Then
            CellAddr = CellAddr & "," & aCell.Address
        End If
    Next

    CellAddr = Mid(CellAddr, 2)

    If Len(Trim(CellAddr)) <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cell(s) " & CellAddr & " is now equal to Yes"
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I'll update my question, however I would need individual pop ups for each cell as there will be cell specific information in the pop up

Comment: @Xeo what is the "yes"'s cell formula? What does it depend on? Also, you original question should be solved now. Try not to edit your question in a way to invalidate the currently provided answers. Maybe it's worth considering asking another questions?

Comment: @Xeo: I can update that in my code as it is a very simple fix but since :@mehow posted his solution first, I would recommend going ahead with his answer :)

Comment: The "Yes" cells formula is for example =IF(AND(G2>=B2,G2<=C2),"Yes","No")